# Direct limits of locally convex spaces and embeddings

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I was thinking about whether [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130294/directed-limits-of-topological-spaces-and-embeddings) positive result would hold in the category of locally convex spaces also...

Here is what I got so far: The direct limit of a locally convex system consists of the final topology on the direct limit of the underlying linear system.  (I tried to prove this formally [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131936/construction-of-colimit-via-semi-final-lift).)  So the direct limit of the vector spaces is $X:=\oplus_\alpha X_\alpha/\sim$ where $\sim$ is the subspace generated by the all elements of the form $x-f_{\alpha\beta}(x)$.

Because we deal with directed posets there is another, nicer representation of $X$, namely the set $\sqcup_\alpha X_\alpha/\sim$ where $\sqcup$ denotes disjoint union and $x\sim y$ for $x\in X_\alpha,y\in X_\beta$ iff there exists some $\alpha,\beta\preceq\gamma$ such that $f_{\alpha\gamma}(x)=f_{\beta\gamma}(y)$ (compare again with Stefan's brilliant answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130294/directed-limits-of-topological-spaces-and-embeddings)).  Addition can then always be carried out in a common domain, i.e. $[x]_\sim+[y]_\sim:=[f_{\alpha\gamma}(x)+f_{\beta\gamma}(y)]_\sim$.  I will denote with $X$ only this alternative construction from here on.

So the embedding $g_\alpha:X_\alpha\rightarrow X$ is closed on its image iff for any closed $A\subseteq X_\alpha$ and $x\in X_\alpha\setminus A$ there is some neighbourhood $U\in{\cal U}(x)$ in $X$ such that $U\cap A=\emptyset$, i.e. $X_\alpha\cap\overline{g_\alpha(A)}=A$.

But that means for $\alpha\preceq\beta$ we have to find open, convex neighbourhoods $U_\beta\in{\cal U}(f_{\alpha\beta}(x))$ in $X_\beta$ which do not intersect with $f_{\alpha\beta}(x)$ and which are consistent w.r.t. the $f_{\beta\gamma}$, i.e. $f_{\beta\gamma}^{-1}(U_\gamma)=U_\beta$ whenever $\alpha\preceq\beta\preceq\gamma$.  This is exactly the condition for an induced basic neighbourhood in $X$.  (For $\alpha\npreceq\beta$ we can choose the $U_\beta$ by passing down from some $\alpha,\beta\preceq\gamma$.)

Now here is where I'm kind of stuck, it seems to me like there is no easy way out and countexamples could be found.  I asked myself [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134111/consistent-choice-of-elements-in-inverse-directed-system) more general question with the problem of finding a consistent choice of neighbourhoods in mind and found a counterexample but I'm not sure if I can transform it so to also disprove this question.